# Detect when mouse enter QGraphicsItem with button down

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I want to detect when the mouse cursor moves in over a `QGraphicsItem` while a mouse button is pressed, i.e. the button is pressed before the mouse enters the item. My first idea was to use `hoverEnterEvent`, but it doesn't seem to trigger when the left mouse button is pressed. My other idea was to use `dragEnterEvent`, but it doesn't seem to trigger at all (even though I have used `setAcceptDrops(True)`.

What is the best way to detect when the cursor moves on top of an item and the mouse button is pressed?

Comment: You may have to filter the mouse events at the graphics scene level, and add some notification to each widget that the mouse is over.  However, I would have thought that the drag events should have worked.

Comment: I am faced with the same problem. Would like to hear an answer. Will checkout drag events.

Answer (score 4):

I just found this question, I know it's old, but I hope my answer will be useful for someone with this problem.

In the `QGraphicsView` or `QGraphicsScene` derived class override the `mouseMoveEvent`  method and check the event's `buttons` property to know what buttons are currently pressed. Here's an example code in PyQt4 from a small project I'm working on:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    buttons = event.buttons()
    pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
    object = self.scene().itemAt(pos)

    type = EventTypes.MouseLeftMove  if (buttons & Qt.LeftButton)  else\
           EventTypes.MouseRightMove if (buttons & Qt.RightButton) else\
           EventTypes.MouseMidMove   if (buttons & Qt.MidButton)   else\
           EventTypes.MouseMove

    handled = self.activeTool().handleEvent(type, object, pos)

    if (not handled):
        QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `mouseMoveEvent()` and `mousePressEvent()`. If they do not help you then you'll need to reimplement virtual method

```
bool QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent ( QEvent * event )
```

Check the mouse button state inside and call the appropriate event handler.